# CSS Hover Effects Persisting When I Don't Want It To

Tags: css, hover

I've got a div styled to be a circle with an image and some text centered inside of it.
Without hovering, the circle and image are shown while the text is transparent.
When hovering, the circle border starts flashes (webkit animation), the image's opacity is lowered, and the text becomes visible.

When writing/testing this code in Firefox, everything works as desired, but on Chrome, the changes from the hover effect persist and I don't want them to (namely, the image opacity stays lowered, and the text remains visible. Continuing to hover on the div, however, makes the border flash as intended.

I've got all the correct webkit/moz/ms/o transitions and animations, but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong (or if this is just one of the deficiencies that comes from using Chrome).

My code for the div and all its elements is:

```
<div class='players'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='span6'>
            <div class='matchup'>
                <p class='team'>SOMETEAMNAME</p>
                <p class='name'>SOMENAME</p>
                <img src='SOMEIMAGE'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.matchup {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    border-radius: 125px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.matchup img {  
    position: static;
    margin-top: -22%;
    opacity: 1;

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.matchup p {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    color: transparent; 

    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: 0.5s ease;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.team {
    font-size: 25px;
}
.name {
    font-size: 45px;
}
.map {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -70%;
}
.matchup:hover {
    -webkit-animation: matchup-active 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: matchup-active 1s infinite;
    -ms-animation: matchup-active 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: matchup-active 1s infinite;
    animation: matchup-active 1s infinite;

    p {
        color: #ff6600;
    }
    img {
        opacity: 0.2;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes matchup-active {
    0% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
    50% {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes matchup-active {
    0% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
    50% {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes matchup-active {
    0% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
    50% {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
}
@keyframes matchup-active {
    0% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
    50% {
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    100% {
        border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Updated with a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sicophrenic/qvJ94/
It's not styled perfectly (i.e. images and stuff aren't centered), but the problem I'm having shows up (in Chrome and works fine in Firefox).

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: okay done: http://jsfiddle.net/sicophrenic/qvJ94/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `.matchup` add `color:transparent;`

on `.matchup:hover` add `color: #ff6600;`

on `.matchup p` add `color: inherit;`

because `.matchup:hover p` is not a valid selector.

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvJ94/1/)

Comment: This only fixes the text issue, but i think you can use a similar technique for the other problems.

Comment: i just noticed something in the fiddle you posted: is ".matchup:hover img {}" a valid selector? you mentioned that ".matchup:hover p {}" isn't a valid selector.

Comment: also, is there a specific reason why what i had before worked as intended on firefox but not chrome?

Comment: i am not sure why it worked in firefox, and I am pretty sure you can't ever select with `:pseudo tag {}` but i could be wrong. Maybe firefox lets you do this.

Comment: something i realized i forgot to mention is that the reason why i had something like `.matchup:hover p {}` was because i was using LESS and when i posted it here i converted it to css using an online converter